# Which version of typescript am I using, global or local?

Tags: typescript

I use typescript to compile my application, but I'm suspect to think that it is not compiling the way I want it to. I have a solution that has 3 package.json.

the following packages have the typescript versions
Root package -"^3.1.3"
Client package -  "^2.9.2"
Server package -  "^2.9.2"

I use gulp and webpack to compile from the Root. BUT!!!!!!!!!!!
My global version of typescript is 3.75

What verison of typescript is being used? Does a global install override the local versions?

Thanks!

Comment: What command are you running to compile your application?

Comment: @AlexWayne Good question. The application has gulp calling webpack. The web pack uses  the tsconfig.json in the root directory then uses some TerserPlugin. And The TerserPlugin references the tsconfig. So it's magic, but I'll investigate further and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @AlexWayne Upon further review. It's not using TerserPlugin to compile. It's using ts-loader.